# fscanf() in C, format for varying length line

Tags: c, file, file-io

So I have a file which contains data in the form:

```
...
5,25,15,16,1,3,Dwyfor_Meirionnydd
5,34,33,26,12,22,Gower
5,7,28,35,4,23,Islwyn
2,20,12,Llanelli
5,4,5,17,7,21,Merthyr_Tydfil_and_Rhymney
5,5,4,35,28,27,Monmouth
4,5,14,19,15,Montgomeryshire
7,0,32,17,5,12,20,33,Neath
2,38,24,Newport_East
...
```

And I need to read each line and put it in the structure such that the first unsigned integer is stored, the next n unsigned integers are stored in an array and then the string at the end is stored. So as an example the second line would be:

```
number-of-elements: 5
array: {34,33,26,12,22}
name: "Gower"
```

The `number` tells us howmany items are in the `array`. I have a struct for this data. How would I go about creating a format for this?

Comment: Something like `struct{int length, int *data, char *name};` and `malloc`.

Comment: This is called CSV (comma separated variable) parsing, and there are a number of CSV parsing strategies, but my favourite if i am doing it from scratch is to break the file out into lines, then break the line down into an array of strings, then into numbers etc.

Comment: @Owl Most (all?) CSV parsers are bad at handling this specific format, because they expect tabular data. OP’s data is *not* tabular (there are no equal numbers of columns for all rows, and the data is in fact nested).

Comment: `, ` is the delimiter - read each lime till you find `\n` and while reading a new line - take a temp `char` array to read and store characters from the file till you meet the delimiter - on finding that use `atoi` and `memset` the temp array. Read the entire thing tilll `EOF` - A lot is missing from my comment which you need to figure

Comment: I do have an existing structure and the first integer tells us how many items are in the array. (Edited question for clarity)

Comment: Can the string at the end be empty or contain spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd just use separate calls to fscanf in a loop to read elements:

```
struct entry {
    int   data_size;
    int   *data;
    char  *name;
};


while (fscanf(input, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    struct entry *e = malloc(sizeof *e);
    e->data_size = num;
    e->data = malloc(num * sizeof e->data[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        if (fscanf(input, " ,%d", &e->data[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data format error\n");
            exit(1); } }
    if (fscanf(input, " ,%ms", &e->name) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Data format error\n");
        exit(1); }
    // read a record into 'e' -- store it into a data structure somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function doesn't support a variable number of formats.  You would need to change what you pass to the function based on the number of elements.

The best way to handle this is to read a line, then use `strtok` to split it into tokens, then use `sscanf` to parse out each individual element in a loop.

```
char line[100];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    int count, i;
    int *array;
    char *name, *p;

    // read the count
    p = strtok(line, ",");
    sscanf(p, "%d", &count);

    // allocate space for the array
    array = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    // read each element
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        sscanf(p, "%d", array + i);
    }

    // read the name
    p = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    name = strdup(p);

    // do something with count, array, and name
}
```

Note that this assumes each line in the file is well formed and therefore doesn't validate the format.